# Bigquery Table not Updating quickly

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm running multiple data ingestion tasks into BigQuery and some tables are taking much longer to update than others. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and what is the best practices if I want to load data into tables for analytics on a recurring basis?

Specifically, I have two tables that I'm writing into using the [Python Client for Google BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html). The code looks something like this

```py
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
bq_client.insert_rows_from_dataframe(table=orders, dataframe=orders_df)
bq_client.insert_rows_from_dataframe(table=order_items, dataframe=order_items_df)
```

I have logging indicating that X rows have been written to each table, but I do not see any updated information when querying the tables. When looking into monitoring, I see that the `order_items` has been updated within the last 15 minutes or so, but the `orders` table has not been updated for hours. When I query within the BigQuery UI or other tools, I also do not see fresh data that should be in the tables according to logs. Both tables are created via `pandas` and only the `order_items` table seems to have this "Streaming buffer statistics" section.

[image]

Comment: When you write query on table `SELECT * FROM ...` , you are not able to view all records?

Comment: When I do that, it only shows records before the last modified date.

Comment: You may refer to this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability documentation for this expected behavior.